# Переменная PATH_INFO всегда пустая при использовании fastcgi на MacOS

Tags: python, nginx, macos, fastcgi

Пытаюсь запустить python-приложение на MacOS, которое по историческим причинам работает с fastcgi. Установил nginx через homebrew и напиcал вот такой простой конфиг:

```
server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen      3000;
 
    location / {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    localhost:8082;
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю приложение на порту 8082 и обращаюсь на 3000 порт через браузер, получаю одинаковый ответ, независимо от uri. Долго разбирался в чем дело, в итоге понял, что Flask в качестве ключа для поиска обработчика использует значение из переменной `PATH_INFO`. И эта переменная при любом запросе у меня пустая. Поэтому он всегда думает, что запрашивают главную страницу.

Проблема воспроизводится только на MacOS. На линуксе с таким же конфигом nginx все в порядке. Другие переменные на месте, например в `REQUEST_URI` лежит верный путь.

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Сравните и покажите содержимое файлов fastcgi_params на линуксе и макоси

Comment: @AlexeyTen да, действительно в MacOS этой переменной нет по-умолчанию и надо добавлять ее руками. Спасибо.